# What is the best way to host an ASP.NET MVC6 Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2015

If I understand correctly part of the motivation of ASP.NET vNext is to reduce overhead. An MVC6 application can be self hosting. My question is what is the best practice way of hosting a ASP.NET vNext application. Is there something similar to the WCF activation services that monitor the health of the service or is there some way of doing this from within the application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "best" way to host ASP.NET MVC 6 is to choose the way that best matches your app's needs, of course! But that perhaps isn't so helpful as far as advice goes.

First, you need to consider the requirements of the application, such as:

- Does it need to run cross-platform?
- Does it need health management?
- Does it need to use existing IIS modules?
- Does it need to run in the context of another application?
- Does it need to use Windows Authentication?
- And no doubt many more requirements...

Here's a brief summary of the various hosting options and their pros/cons:

- IIS is perhaps the most well-known host. It has been hardened for well over a decade. Many popular modules are available for it, including providing various security features. IIS has built-in support for Windows Authentication, logging, app warmup, health management, remote administration, and [lots of other features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services#Features).
- IIS Express shares the same codebase as IIS, but can be run without admin privileges.
- [Kestrel](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer) is a cross-platform web server that is being written as part of ASP.NET 5 and is currently most suited for development work. It's very lightweight, which can be both good (nothing in the way!) and bad (not very many features).
- Self-host is where you are master of your own domain. Nearly everything is up to you, including figuring out what should happen if there is an unrecoverable error. Self-hosting is a great option if you need to host a server within your app (e.g. a client app that uses a web server to host UI or services that the app directly uses).

There is certainly no one "best" way to host an ASP.NET MVC 6 app, but there are certainly many solutions catered to a variety of needs.

In my answer to [ASP.NET vNext is host agnostic, what does it deeply mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25512549/31668) I covered a few other aspects of host agnosticism.

Answer (score 2):

## ASP.NET Core 1.1 Answer

- The 1.1 release added GZIP compression and response caching.
- Kestrel is still not security tested and should not be used without IIS or NGINX as a reverse proxy. This will change at some point.
- Kestrel still does not support HTTP 2.0.
- Using IIS or NGINX with MVC 6 is slower than MVC 5. Yes MVC 6 is supposed to be faster but only if you use Kestrel on it's own.

## ASP.NET Core 1.0 Answer

IIS or NGINX is by far the best host for an ASP.NET MVC 6 application. Below are a list of features you will not get without IIS or NGINX without lots of extra work. Note that all of these features require a small amount of config in the web.config file.

- The Kestrel web server has not been battle hardened and tested for security. It's not supposed to be exposed to the internet...yet.
- Kestrel does not support HTTP 2.0.

  - GZIP compression of HTTP requests for saving bandwidth and better performance. This alone is a big enough reason.
  - Error handling outside of ASP.NET. What happens when you have a .dll file missing? Well IIS will still show an error page and you can customize the error page too.
  - Dynamic IP security - During a Denial of Service (DoS) attack, a very simple and small 403.501 or 403.502 Forbidden static error page is displayed.