# What does it mean that ASP.NET 5 supports OWIN?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have been using ASP.NET MVC for almost 4 years. I love it and I'm very interested in ASP.NET vNext(maybe 5). I want to know the lifecycle of it(not MVC 6).

As described [in Microsoft's ASP.NET 5 Overview](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/aspnet-5-overview),

> The new pipeline also supports OWIN.

What does the word *supports* mean here? Does it mean ASP.NET vNext implements OWIN's lifecycle or something like "we can add middleware to ASP.NET vNext applications"?

Comment: @Kate Gregory Thank you for editing my question.

Comment: For a lengthier answer that goes into some of the history, check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431750/asp-net-vnext-is-host-agnostic-what-does-it-deeply-mean/25512549#25512549

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means there is an OWIN adapter so that existing OWIN components can be reused in the new pipeline. Use the Microsoft.AspNet.Owin package for that. An example is available here: https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Owin.IAppBuilderBridge

However for any new code you write, write ASP.NET 5 middleware, and the lifecycle is determined by your setup in startup.cs

So this means you can:

1. Run OWIN components inside an ASP.NET 5 application
2. Run ASP.NET 5 on any OWIN server like NoWin

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? How would one use OWIN in the new version?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do with Owin. In general this package will enable wrapping existing owin components and enable them to run in the new pipeline. However not every single feature in Owin is supported (so think Owin yet, Katana no). It's probably a good idea to post a specific question to get a more specific answer.